# resize on responsive css div using margin-top etc

Tags: html, css

Hi to all and good day!

anybody can give some advice on how do my css code can be done, please see the code below. my current status when i do resize my browser for responsive purpose.

```
         <div style="width:100%; height:auto; position:relative;">
           <div style="min-width:300px; height:500px; float:left; background-color:orange;">
               <!-- some content here -->
           </div>
           <div style="min-width:300px; height:200px; float:left; margin-top:300px; background-color:green;">
               <!-- some content here -->
           </div>
          </div>
```

the output of that code has a big distance above which i put the css margin-top:300px; when i do resize the browser up to the smallest size.

is that possible to solve???..

Comment: use `%` instead of `px`

Comment: @VitorinoFernandes , output still the same and i put margin-top:80%; any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

You could use media queries.

```
@media screen and (max-width:450px)
{
  .divID{
           //code goes in here
           margin-top:50px;
   }

}
```

So here, when the screen width is `450px` or less, the `margin-top` will be reduced to `50px`.

And I would suggest using `%` or `em` rather than `px` unit. Because `%` or `em` helps to adapt the element `width` or `height` based on the available screen width. `pixel` doesn't do this.

Here is some reference to using media queries. [REFERENCE](http://coding-4fun.blogspot.in/2015/02/responsive-web-design.html)

Comment: it will give me more space above my div :(

Comment: @JuanTamad what did you try ? Post the code if you could.

Answer (score 0):

You may should consider of using a framework.

In that case: Use a media query. Have a [look](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

Answer (score 0):

if I don't understand wrong you want the next: when you resize the browser the margin top will be 30px (example)

you can use [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/CSS/Media_queries)

like this:

```
<div style="width:100%; height:auto; position:relative;">
           <div style="min-width:300px; height:500px; float:left; background-color:orange;">
               <!-- some content here -->
           </div>
           <div id="div2" style="min-width:300px; height:200px; float:left; margin-top:300px; background-color:green;">
               <!-- some content here -->
           </div>
          </div>
```

CSS code:

```
@media (max-width: 300px) {
#div2{
margin-top:30px;
}
}
```

also you should use CSS file instead of write the style in the html

Comment: if i do resize the browser to 300px; width, will take effect but only if i reach the amount of size in the browser and if i do not still has the problem. any other solutions?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly?